# Bold text line-height is higher than normal text line-height

Tags: html, css

Must be something basic I'm missing here. I thought that font-weight:bold should not change how much vertical space the text takes. Especially when the line-height is set to be higher than the font-size.

http://jsfiddle.net/Arkkimaagi/7xAyy/

On my OSX chrome those three text heights do not match. The second one with font-weight:bold is 1px higher than the rest. The third div is just an example of fixing the problem (poorly)

I'm trying to set the line-height to something specific (18px) here, to have "vertical rhythm"

My question is, how can I have bold and normal text both with same line-height as in the example?

[edit:] 
here's what I see on my mac
[image: Example of the problem on my osx]

Also, here is what I ment by "vertical rhythm": http://www.alistapart.com/articles/settingtypeontheweb
 - the baseline grid is more visible in the example: http://www.alistapart.com/d/settingtypeontheweb/example_grid.html

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Firefox on Windows. In theory font weight shouldn't change line height. What do you mean with "vertical rhythm"? What exactly are you trying to do? Setting line height is generally never the best solution for anything.

Comment: You could try using `padding` instead of `line-height`. You might also want to inlcude an image for those who do not have OSX.

Comment: Okay, I've tried to be more clear. I added an image showing what I see and a couple of links that explain the vertical rhythm or baseline grid. The grid is what I'm trying to do here. This example is just a small part of the thing that I had problems with.

Comment: ybakos, lets not start a "html/css is not a programming language"-thing here. I did tag the question html and css.

Comment: ybakos, after your comment I did double check that I did not find a better stackexchange site for my question. There does not seem to be webdev site. I think this is better than "Q and A for pro webmasters". Where should I have asked the question?

Comment: Viruzzo, setting line height should be the best way to set the line height to a certain size, right? I'm trying to get the baseline grid working.

Comment: Mikko, this seems to be a browser glitch when displaying the fonts. If you play a little with different font-sizes/line-heights you will see that the behavior varies a little. Try for example font-size:14px and line-height:20px. No problem happens here. I think the browser has issues with some math when the font is bold.

Comment: beatriz, submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It completely depends on the fonts you are using. Nothing about OSX or Chrome text rendering would ensure that two different fonts (and Helvetica-neue and Helvetica-neue-bold are two different fonts) would have the same vertical space even at the same font-size and line height.

Even though that is too much to ask you might think that two different fonts from the same family might be consistent, and usually they are, but sadly the two fonts you have chosen are not.

Comment: It is strange, though, because the line-height was explicitly set in `px`, which should cause it to be the same height no matter what the actual size of the font is. `line-height:18px;` should be the same no matter if the font is `1px` or `100px` in size.

Comment: Thanks Nate B, that's what I thought too. 18px is 18px, right?

Comment: Yea, I would expect differences across browsers/platforms, but I still find it odd that it is rendering differently right next to each other like that.

Comment: it's causing a havoc on my grid :(

Comment: consider two blocks of text, one small (10px) and one large (21px), but both with the same line height (21px). Although the space between baselines is 21px in both cases, the baselines for the two blocks do not coincide, or sit on the same grid.

Comment: holeyloop, I do not care about the text not sitting nicely next to each other. The problem comes when I add content after the text. Like the hr element that I have on my example. It should be 1px higher so that rest of the page would also align to grid. (And no, I can not just move it 1px higher with margins as I do not know how many rows of text there will be.)

Comment: I'm sure you do care - what i mean is setting line-height to 18px doesn't make it 18px (or multiple of) high. What you are trying todo is impossible

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes adding top vertical align will solve this (depending on font size/family).

```
strong { vertical-align: top; }
```

In your fiddle example, because you have set a line height on the container (div), you can simply add the following:

```
span { line-height: 1em; }
```

Comment: the problem I had was that the set of <p> tags were shifting up when one line became bold on hover.  Adding vertical-align: top to the css fixed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Setting an absolute line-height on both the container and the bold text, or giving bold text a line height of 1em (as DaveC says above) both fix this, e.g. from the jsfiddle you just need to add `line-height: 1em`

```
.bolded span {
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

Or why not follow HTML standards and use the correct tags instead of bolded spans? E.g.

```
strong, em { line-height: 1em }
```

Comment: I do not want to set the line-height to 1em as I want the line-height to be precisely 18px like I stated in my question. If I'd have multiple rows of bolded words, the alignment would be off with 1em = 13px line-height letters. The sample code is just that, sample code. Changing the code to use strong instead of span does not help here as I simply wanted to demonstrate the line problems.

Comment: I think you've missed the point of my reply. The line height is exactly 18px. Using 1em on the child elements means the inherit the computed height of 18px rather thaqn applying their own value. was not suggesting changing the line-height of the div, but specifying 1em for the bold content so it inherits the div's line-height.

Comment: (*Correction - I ran out of time to edit my reply*)
Using 1em on the child elements means they inherit the div's line-height of 18px rather than applying their own value. I've tested this in OS X Chrome and it's a nice fix. Do you not think asking 'is there a better way to handle this' then downvoting someone for suggesting one is a bit rude?

Comment: This fixed it for me, thanks. In my case, the problem only appeared when I set the font weight to 900 on the bold. But this fixed it regardless.

Comment: OMG, the time I checked this comment, I did not test this as thoroughly as I did now and boy was I wrong. I'm sorry for downvoting you, I'd upvote now if I could, but unless you edit this answer, I am unable to. For the matter, I have no idea why setting the line-height to 1em in the span does not set the line height in the span to be same size as the font-size, but to surrounding line-height instead. Please forgive me from years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered very similar problem with Chivo font: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/chivo. Right now I'm using the ugliest hack (works on current Firefox and Chrome, IE untested yet):

```
strong { vertical-align: top; position: relative; top: -1px; }
```

I try not give up on Chivo quite hard as you see ...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a font issue. I found differing line heights for the italic variant of Nunito (Google Web Font). When I switched to a reworked version of that font called "Nunito Sans" the issue was resolved.