# Why is vertical alignment afftected by font-weight with Crimson Text font?

Tags: html, css, fonts, vertical-alignment

Recently I have been playing around with the anchor tags' css of the page http://nate.fm/articles/ If you assign border around the link `Light` or `Pro-Life vs Pro-Birth` and change their `font-weight` to more than `500` then suddenly the vertical alignment changes from middle to top. Below I have added images showing this:

**Font Weight 700:**

[image]

**Font Weight 500:**

[image]

More to the surprise, this bug disappears for any other font family than *Crimson Text*. I tried to replicate the bug on local but failed.

Could anyone shed some light over this bug?

Comment: With chrome on mac it does not change anything between 500 and 700.

Comment: @GermanoPlebani On my windows 10 chrome 53.0.2785.143 it changes. Something's surely wrong with this font. On [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40062411/3429430) another user is having a related bug which doesn't appear on my window10 operating system.

Comment: Individual fonts are only designed to work at one particular size, increasing the weight creates a faux bold weight, and you should not expect it to work. Font families may have bolder and lighter weights and changing the `font-weight` can choose between them. You will need to set this behaviour up with custom fonts, by using `@font-face {font-family: xxxxx}` .

Comment: Saying that I'm unsure exactly why the line height is messing up, I'll see what I can find out.

Comment: Here is an explanation of faux bold and faux italic fonts http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2013/09/20/better-web-typography-with-font-weight-autohinting-and-font-feature-settings/

Comment: Here is another article from A List Apart regarding faux bold. http://alistapart.com/article/say-no-to-faux-bold

Comment: I should mention the best way to fix this is to use a true bold version of the font.

Comment: @Sarcoma But there is another problem. I would try bold or regular versions if the bug could be replicated. When I use the same font in a sample html file on my computer then the bug doesn't appear.

Comment: Is Crimson Text a font you have installed locally? And which browser are you using? does it occur in more than one browser?

Comment: @Sarcoma No I haven't installed it locally. I was using the [google Crimson text font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Crimson+Text) with `link` tag. The bug appears on all browsers(chrome, IE11 and firefox). Does it occur on your browsers too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126073/discussion-between-sarcoma-and-user31782).

Comment: @Sarcoma I have replicated the issue on my local pc too. The problem occurs when faux bold version is added in the stylesheet. In this case one should **not use the bold version** as opposed to what you said.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned it only happens with Crimson Text, it's probably just the way that font renders when bold.  A similar question was asked here: [Bold text line-height is higher than normal text line-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376795/bold-text-line-height-is-higher-than-normal-text-line-height)

I played around with disabling all the other styles on the page, to see if maybe something was overriding it, but couldn't find any culprits.

A possible work around might just be adding some padding-top.

Comment: In the question you linked the bug is about `line-height`. But in my situation line height doesn't change. Here the `box-sizing` is getting affected. Also as Germono mentions the bug doesn't appear on mac OS. So it's not the font renders designed it this way; it is a browser/OS specific bug.

Comment: @user31782 The asker refers to it as line-height  but if you read the answer that was accepted, it's mention that it's because of the font itself rather than line-height.  I understood it to mean there's an issue with the way this font renders - specifically on some browsers/OS.